# Pass a TextBox Value as a link and a parameter to another webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, html-email, mailmessage

I am trying to send a email from my webform1 once a new work order has been created, however when the user clicks the workorder number i want that workorder number to be passed as a parameter to webform2. the code i use to send the email:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
mm.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("some@some.com");//who send
mm.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("some@gmail.com"));
mm.To.Add(new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("some@some.com"));
mm.Subject = "WorkOrders Created With Type Safety";
mm.Body = "WorkOrderNumber" + ": &nbsp;" 
+ "<a href=\"http://localhost:49695/Safety.aspx?=WorkOrderNum=\">" 
+ TextBox13.Text + "</a>" 
+ "<-Click on the Work Order Number" + "<br><br/>" 
+ "Requestor" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxRequestor.Text 
+ "<br><br/>" + "Date" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxDate.Text 
+ "<br><br/>" + "Department" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxDepartment.Text
+ "<br><br/>" + "Completion Date" + ":&nbsp;" 
+ TextBoxCompletionDate.Text + "<br><br/>" + "Machine Description" 
+ ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxMachineDescription.Text + "<br><br/>" 
+ "Machine Location" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxMachineLocation.Text 
+ "<br><br/>" + "Work Required" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxWorkRequired.Text
+ "<br><br/>" + "Status" + ":&nbsp;" + TextBoxStatus.Text;
mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"];
client.Send(mm);
```

when the above code is sent as an email the result looks like this and the 14 is clickable link:

```
WorkOrderNumber:  14<-Click on the Work Order Number

Requestor: Mark

Date: 01/07/2015

Department: IT

Completion Date: 01/08/2015

Machine Description: Fan

Machine Location: SomeLocation

Work Required: Needs Installing 

Status: Open
```

so then on webform2 i would be able to use this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var workourdernum = Request.QueryString["WorkOrderNum"];
        }
```

so i just want that number from TextBox13.Text be passed along with the link, i looked online people are accomplishing similar task via Response.Redirect()

Comment: What have you tried?  I think something like `Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx?WorkOrderNum=" + TextBox13.Text);` would be a very basic way to do it so long as you don't mind no validation or error handling.

Comment: @BenRobinson how would i integrate Response.Redirect in an email body which has html enabled?/

Comment: You can't, I thought you wanted to redirect the user on the web page that generates the email, i.e. send the email then redirect to another page.  You can't cause a user to be redirected to a web page when they open an email. Do you just want to put a click able link in the email? It looks like your code already does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```
 "<a href=\"http://localhost:49695/Safety.aspx?WorkOrderNum=" + 
+ TextBox13.Text + "\">" + TextBox13.Text + "</a>" 
+ "<-Click on the Work Order Number" + "<br><br/>"
```

You'd be passing the work order number in the query string.  Your web page could then just extract the work order number from the query string.

You'll get HTML that looks like this:

```
 <a href="http://localhost:49695/Safety.aspx?WorkOrderNum=123">123</a>
```

The code you already have (for `Page_Load`) would work perfectly to extract the work order number in the second page.

Comment: Exactly what i need how ever on the pageload even the Request.QueryString["WorkOrderNum"] is getting an value for  {WorkOrderNum%3d16} why is that happening and my TextBox10.Text in the other webform is getting "" as the value

Comment: i see you edited the code, yup it all works perfectly thanks Ann, once i reach 15 reputations ill come and vote this answer up as well ;)

Comment: Hey for some reason I am getting this error when I pass the value from webform1 to webform2 "index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list." Have you seen this error before?? please help

Comment: It sounds like it might be coming from that code I put in and later deleted, if you're using that.  If you use `String.Format`, and have placeholders (like {0}, {1}, {2},etc.) you need to have as many values as you have placeholder numbers.  Ex:  `String.Format("{0} and {1} and {2}", arg0, arg1, arg2);`.  Here's some guidance:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format

Comment: Thanks Ann L actually it was a dumb mistake on my part, for some reason i was using a filter on my select query and that too on my workordernum so it was throwing that error, i removed the filter and it worked, but yea ill look into the string.format article as well maybe i would be required to use it down the line some where.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to pass value from one form to another.

webform1.aspx - for example on button click event

```
Response.Redirect("webform2.aspx?number=" + TextBox13.Text);
```

webform2.aspx

```
int passedNumber; 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request["number"] != null)
   {
       passedNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Request["number"]);
   } 
}
```

Now you can do what ever you want with that number on webform2.

Comment: yea that's correct bud i agree but that is only when your working from one webform to another, but in my case the flow is as such webform1-> workorder created -> email sent with a clickable link to webform2-> which has all the workorders but i want to receive the workordernum from the email link soo i can filter out the workorder on webform2 u see what i mean, so your answer is correct but how do i accomplish this from an email link for example mm.body = response.redirect(("webform2.aspx?number=" + TextBox13.Text) + the next item would be cool if html could handle that but it doesnt